# Is there any possibility to run all test suites and generate report?

Tags: python, squish

Is there any command with squish runner or any option available in squish to run all the test suites in single run and generate report of complete project?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that is built into squishrunner, but if you specify the same "html" report folder for each execution, the suite reports will be stored in it and linked in the index.html page, to view them conveniently.

Executing one after the other via a shell script or batch file is simple, just add each squishrunner call into such a file.

As for reporting, please look into Squish Test Center, for which you should have 2 licenses per each Squish GUI Tester Tester license. This is because the HTML report format is deprecated and lacks features.

Comment: Thank you. It works.
Squish will not allow to add any external plugin to generate report. Is that correct?

Comment: No, Squish does not support "report plug-ins". Instead, choose one of the supported report generators and write a converter to the desired format yourself.